# How to get the date a unix file was created in mono

Tags: file, date, unix, mono, inode

I recently discovered the Mono.Posix assembly, which has all kinds of awesome goodies for accessing unix file attributes with Mono. However, there are only 3 dates that I can see that are tracked by the UnixFileInfo class:

- LastWriteTime
- LastAccessTime
- LastStatusChangeTime

I'm working on OS X. I assume that LastWriteTime would correspond to Date Modified in Finder, and LastAccessTime would correspond to Date Last Opened. LastStatusChangeTime isn't necessary for my application. However, I'm not sure how I would access the Date Created attribute through Mono.

I found this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4/50184#50184

and that seems to point to the fact that I can get this date from the inode.

If I run

```
stat -f %B <file>
```

on my mac, it prints out the birth date of the file.

I can see that Mono.Posix has built in native syscalls to get the data. How might I use them to get that date?

Comment: What is wrong with **File.GetCreationTime**?

Comment: Will that work? It was my understanding that the System.IO from the .NET framework doesn't support Unix files

Comment: The mono runtime will call the **stat** or **lstat** syscall behind the scene.